# Converting from Olson time zone to Posix time zone

Tags: c++, boost, posix, boost-date-time

Is there a way in C/C++ to convert from Olson time zone format to POSIX time zone format.

```
Example: for Auckland
Olson time zone format: TZ="Pacific/Auckland"
Posix time zone format: TZ="NZST-12:00:00NZDT-13:00:00,M10.1.0,M3.3.0"
```

Comment: You can compare the time zone to the Olson format, and return the Posix format for it.  `if (tz == "Pacific/Auckland") return "NZST-12:00:00NZDT-13:00:00,M10.1.0,M3.3.0";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not possible because the POSIX time zone format only allows for zero or two UTC offset changes per year, and does not allow for different rules for different years.  The IANA (Olson) data base is more flexible than that.

If you allow for multiple Posix time zones and a start/end for when that Posix time zone is valid, it is *almost* possible, but not easy.

I've been working on a tool to do this, and needed to make an extension to the Posix time zone format to allow for "permanent DST".  This is done by allowing the string to begin with an offset, making the initial standard abbreviation optional, and allowing the rule set (everything beginning with `,`) also be optional.  Example:

```
"EST5" yields a constant offset of -5h with 0h save and "EST abbreviation.
"5EDT" yields a constant offset of -4h with 1h save and "EDT" abbreviation.
```

Even with these extensions, I'm not positive it is possible to capture a complete IANA time zone with Posix time zones.  This tool is still under development.

Here is what I current have for Pacific/Auckland (it is unchecked):

```
Pacific/Auckland
*
LMT-11:39:04
1868-11-01 12:20:56
NZMT-11:30
1927-11-05 14:30:00
NZMT-11:30NZST,M11.1.0,M3.1.0
1928-10-13 14:30:00
NZMT-11:30NZST-12,M10.2.0,M3.3.0
1933-10-07 14:30:00
NZMT-11:30NZST-12,M10.2.0,M4.5.0
1934-09-29 14:30:00
NZMT-11:30NZST-12,M9.5.0,M4.5.0
1940-09-28 14:30:00
-11:30NZST-12
1945-12-31 12:00:00
NZST-12
1974-11-02 14:00:00
NZST-12NZDT,M11.1.0,M2.5.0/3
1975-10-25 14:00:00
NZST-12NZDT,M10.5.0,M3.1.0/3
1989-10-07 14:00:00
NZST-12NZDT,M10.2.0,M3.3.0/3
1990-10-06 14:00:00
NZST-12NZDT,M10.1.0,M3.3.0/3
2007-09-29 14:00:00
NZST-12NZDT,M9.5.0,M4.1.0/3
*
```

The time stamps are implicitly UTC.  The first `*` indicates the beginning of time, and the last `*` indicates the end of time.  Those are open to interpretation of the client reading this transformed database.

Comment: Thanks @Howard for the detailed explanation. I am only interested in the current time zone details and not in the older history that Olson provides. Does it mean I will need to programtically parse the /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Auckland file on Linux?

Comment: Parsing /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Auckland is one option.  Another is hardwiring in your own Posix string (e.g. `"NZST-12NZDT,M9.5.0,M4.1.0/3"`).  Another option is using the timezone facilities in C++20 chrono which are effectively a parser of /usr/share/zoneinfo.  The latter won't get you the Posix string.  But it should provide you with a complete time zone handling facility.

Comment: Indeed, I am using the C++20 chrono facilities to build my IANA->Posix converter.  But I stress that this isn't simple.  But theoretically, it may be possible to build a portable IANA->Posix converter from the C++20 chrono library (modulo some extensions to the Posix format).